# vue.js on click return random selection from array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to get one random item from an array of entries once the user has click a button. But I can't seem to get it working. The only error I get is "Property or method "winner" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"

I'm guessing is because the function isn't running and assigning the value to winner? Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Component code below

```
<template>
    <div class="container-flex">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="entries">

                <div class="entries__header">

                    <div class="entries__header__title">
                        <p>Competition Entries</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="entries__header__search">
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            name="Search" 
                            class="input input--search" 
                            placeholder="Search..." 
                            v-model="search">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="entries__content">
                    <ul class="entries__content__list">
                        <li v-for="entry in filteredEntries">
                            {{ entry.name }} 
                        </li>

                        <li class="winner">{{ winner }}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


                <add-entry :entries.sync="entries"/>

            </div>

            <button 
                @click="pickWinner">Pick Winner</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import addEntry from '@/components/add-entry.vue'

export default {
    name: 'entry-list',
    components: {
        addEntry
    },
    data: function() {

        return {
            search: '',
            entries: [
                {
                    name: 'Geoff'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Stu'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Craig'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Mark'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Zoe'
                }
            ],

        }
    },
    methods: {
        pickWinner() {
            winner: this.entries[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.entries.length)]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        filteredEntries() {
            if(this.search === '') return this.entries
            return this.entries.filter(entry => {
                return entry.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
            })   
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: You don't have `winner` property in your data object. Also your `pickWinner()` function seems wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set up a property called `winnerId` and a computed `winner` and update it

```
data: function() {
    return {
        winnerId: null,
        // ...
    }
},
methods: {
    pickWinner() {
        this.winnerId = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.entries.length)
    }
},
computed: {
    winner() {
         return this.entries[this.winnerId] || null;
    }
}
```

you may need to add some extra error checking still, such as in the template, if `this.winnerId` is null, don't bother showing, or in the computed value, if the winnerId is null, run `this.pickWinner()`, or whatever other additional logic you need.